# Rearranging list in python

Tags: python, list

I need to define a function named "dutch_flag" which takes a list of colors (red, green and blue) and:

Returns color_list rearranged so that 'red' strings come first, 'green' second and 'blue' third.

```
>>> color_list = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'green']
>>> dutch_flag(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'green'])
>>> color_list
['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']
```

So far I have come up with this:

```
color_list = ['red','red','red','red','green','green','red','blue','green','red','blue','red','blue','blue']

def dutch_flag (ls):

#create a list of colors according to their priority
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']

#create a list that keeps track of the number color counts while looping
colorCounts = []

#create a temporary list which will be used to re-create color_list
temp_ls = []

#loop over each color to process color_list
for color in colors:                    #for each colors
    colorCounts.append(ls.count(color))     #remember the color count

    #now add the color (color-count) times to the temp list

    #for each count, append color to the temp_list
    for count in range(ls.count(color)):
        temp_ls.append( color )

#re-define list
ls = temp_ls

#free memory
del temp_ls, colors, colorCounts

#return result
return ls
```

Problem is it does not "rearrange" the input list. I cannot find a way to rearrange in such manner.

Please suggest me a **Simple** solution (or an algorithm) so that an **Absolute Beginner** like me can understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `sorted` with `list.index` as key:

```
>>> color_list = ['red','red','red','red','green','green','red','blue','green','red','blue','red','blue','blue']

>>> colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
>>> sorted(color_list, key= colors.index)
['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue']

>>> colors = ['green', 'blue', 'red']
>>> sorted(color_list, key= colors.index)
['green', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red']
```

Using a function:

```
def dutch_flag(seq, order=('red', 'green', 'blue')):
    return sorted(seq, key= order.index)

#Re-assign the returned value to a variable
new_list = dutch_flag(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'green'])
```

Comment: You don't need `lambda` here. `sorted(seq, key=order.index)` is enough.

Comment: @Suor Ouch! Yes, How did I miss that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **simple** solution: You can sort the list using `sort()` (which will *sort in-place*, in other words, it will *rearrenge* the list) and passing `True` to the parameter `reverse`. You will get the expected result because this will sort the strings alphabetically in the reverse order:

```
def dutch_flag(L):
    L.sort(reverse = True)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> color_list = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'green']
>>> dutch_flag(color_list)
>>> color_list
['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple sort() function should work.

```
color_list = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'green']
color_list.sort(reverse=True)
print(color_list)
['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']
```